# Organize js file in Angular2

Tags: angular

I read the whole [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/styleguide).

It is a good starting point but it lacks some points.

For example: Where should we put the generated javascript files?
By default **tsc** put the files in the same folder of the `.ts` files, but in this way
the project folder become very very dirty.

I have created a "`wwwroot`" folder where I put the generated js, but I dont like this way because I also have to copy the `.css and` `.html` file in the `wwwroot`.

Is there a best practise?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I put my custom js files into a js directory which I place in the assets folder. This way it is accessible by the app when compiled and prepared for distribution or production.

So your file structure should look like this,

```
assets/js/custom.js
```

Then in your `src/index.html` file you can do this,

```
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular 2 and are having troubles with setting this up, I would recommend using the Angular CLI. This will abstract a lot of this away for you and get you up and coding quickly. It's an ideal option to get started so look into it ;).

To answer your question. What I always do is use a tsconfig.json file to define how my typescript compiler works. Here I define my out directory in which the typescript files are compiled.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "out",
"types": [
      "es6-shim",
      "jasmine",
      "lodash",
      "node",
      "toastr"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "out",
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "reports"
  ],
  "version": "2.0.2"
}
```

This is the entire file of one of my configs. See the outDir option.

Comment: Hi KwintenP. I'm also using the outDir property. The question is also focused on the .css and .html files. You "out" dir contains the generated js files, but what about the .html and .css of the components?

Comment: To work with css files and html files I prefer to use Webpack. Webpack is a module bundler that gives you the option to bundle your entire application in a single bundle that can be run in the browser. The angular cli also uses webpack under the hood so check that out.